# Filtering a list of objects with 'OR' on the same field

Tags: filters, tags

I'm trying to use `wp_filter_object_list` to get tags with the slug (for example) "cat" OR "dog" from an array of tags.

My code looks like this:

```
$post_tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'post_tag' );

wp_filter_object_list( $post_tags, array('slug' => 'cat', 'slug' => 'dog'), 'or' );
```

I would expect this to return all tags with the slug "cat" or "dog", but it seems to only be returning the tag with "dog". If I switch the order, I only get "cat". How can I filter the list of tags for both?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't have multiple key value pairs in the same array with the same name, aka 'slug' can only appear once, what you've put is not valid PHP. Instead PHP is trying to be helpful and overwriting `'slug' => 'cat'` with `'slug' => 'dog'` as it's the last item with that key name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function `wp_filter_object_list` can only filter one value.
for your filter try that :

```
$post_tags = array_filter($post_tags, function ($e) {
    return in_array($e->slug, ["dog", "cat"]);
});
```

Comment: The logical operation to perform. `'or'` means only one element from the array needs to match; `'and'` means all elements must match; `'not'` means no elements may match. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_object_list/

Comment: @Drupalizeme the above question does not use `wp_filter_object_list`

Comment: @TomJNowell Not sure what you mean? The above question and answer involve the `wp_filter_object_list`

Comment: @Drupalizeme the above answer eliminates the call to wp_filter_object_list and completely replaces it with an `array_filter` call, your comment would make more sense on the question

Comment: @TomJNowell My comment was to add more to the explanation why this is not working as the OP asked. Not sure why this isn't clear.

Comment: @Drupalizeme Then it belongs on the question, not this answer